# How to enter the directory of a container?

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

How can I access the directories of a container from the node which executes the container?

I have root-access to the master-node. Now I would like to have a look at the `/etc` directory of the `etcd` pod/container.

`kubectl exec` does not help, since it is a distroless image which misses the usual shell tools like `ls` and `tar`.

I use `containerd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use containerd in my local setup and I use remote etcd server. But the idea explained below can be use for local etcd.

1. [Optional step] ssh to etcd node. If using local etcd in master then ignore this step.
2. First find the process ID for the etcd container `ps -aux | grep -i etcd`

[image]

3. Now lets us the magic `/proc` directory to find the `etcd DB location`.

`sudo ls /proc/9591/root/var/lib/etcd`

[image]

4. Navigate to etcd directory
   `sudo ls /proc/9591/root/etc/kubernetes`

[image]

5. Let's check the etcd certiifcates:
   `sudo ls /proc/9591/root/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/`

[image]

Comment: Great! `/proc/PID/root` was new to me.

Comment: +1 but please  when posting console output / settings format it as "`code`" using [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. Also use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following command (be careful when performing operations):

```
nsenter -p -m  -t <processid>
```

basically track the pid of the application inside a container you wish to enter and replace  with it's process id